# Linq C# to Vb .Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq-to-sql

Im struggling trying to convert this code. As well as googling for an answer and reading MSDN documentation i still cant figure this out. Ive also looked at the examples

101 for Visual Basic .Net
101 for C# .Net

Hers some C# code im trying to convert:

```
var asciiCredentials = (from c in credentials
                select c <= 0x7f ? (byte)c : (byte)'?').ToArray();
```

My attempt so far:

```
Dim ascii = (From c In Credentials(Function(x) x= 0x7f .....)
```

But cant figure it out!! I think the Byte conversion is putting me off track.

Can anyone advise

Comment: I've been using C# recently but need to make that transition soon hopefully. It depends on the other guys too as i cant have my projects with C# and rest with VB .Net ;-)

Comment: @Computer Well, you *can* ;)

Comment: Hmm wonder why someone decided to remove the 1 up vote i had for putting in research etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `If` in place of the conditional operator, making the code:

```
Dim asciiCredentials = credentials.Select(Function(x) _
        If(x <= 127, Convert.ToByte(c), Convert.ToByte("?"C)))_
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Boy, it was funny that as soon as you post, the other answers changed to use your `IF`.

Comment: mine had it from start, just missing the space when I copied for some reason

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that Visual Basic has the IIf command that, in some respects, acts like the ternary operator.

```
    Dim ascii = (From ch In s
                Select IIf(Char.GetNumericValue(ch) < 127, Convert.ToByte(ch), Convert.ToByte("?"c))).ToArray()
```

[image: There was a comment saying this didn't compile]

Comment: To create this LINQ query, I loaded VS2013, assigned a value to the string "s", compiled it, and debugged it to validate the results.  Which version of Visual Studio/Visual Basic are you targeting? (Image attached to show it in the debugger.)

Comment: Sorry - I was testing with an 's' similar to what the op used (List<int> probably).

Comment: Not a problem.  I should have posted my entire code block, not just the snippet.

Comment: IIf is not a best solution, since it evaluates both arguments, better use If() instead

Comment: Rustram, very true.  I haven't used VB.NET since 2006, so until this thread I wasn't aware that the short-circuit ternary operator was added in .NET 3.0 to VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim asciiCredentials = (From c In credentials Select If(c <= &H7f, CByte(c), CByte(AscW("?"C)))).ToArray()
```

Taken from here:http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb

They usually do pretty well converting.

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Comment: You're correct, it was missing the select.  I've put that in to make the answer correct, and I'm contacting the conversion site.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim asciiCredentials = (
    From c In credentials
    Select If(c <= &H7f, CByte(c), AscW("?"c))).ToArray()
```